# firestore using "where" and "orderBy"

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to run a simple query on Firestore, using both where and orderBy. The query does not work. After some research, I found out that I might need to build index in Firestore. I did that, but once again, this query does not work.

error result

`The initial orderBy() field "[[FieldPath([lastTime]), true]][0][0]" has to be the same as the where() field parameter "FieldPath([lastChat])" when an inequality operator is invoked. 'package:cloud_firestore/src/query.dart': package:cloud_firestore/src/query.dart:1 Failed assertion: line 456 pos 13: 'field == orders[0][0]`

here is the code:

```
    Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> chatsStream(String email) {
    var result = firestore
        .collection('users')
        .doc(email)
        .collection("chats")
        .where("lastChat", isNotEqualTo: "")
        .orderBy("lastTime", descending: true)
        .snapshots();
    return result;
  }
```

and this is index in firestore:

[image]

sorry for my english, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify an `orderBy` for the `lastChat` field, as `isNotEqualTo` is a range condition (it helps to think of it as `<>` for that purpose):

```
var result = firestore
    .collection('users')
    .doc(email)
    .collection("chats")
    .orderBy("lastChat")
    .where("lastChat", isNotEqualTo: "")
    .orderBy("lastTime", descending: true)
    .snapshots();
```

---

The index on `lastTime` is ascending, but your query is descending. That means the index doesn't match the query, and the database will return no results.

It should actually also log a warning/error with a direct link to create the index with all fields pre-populated (including the correct sort order for `lastTime`).

---

Comment: I've changed the index but still error

Comment: Did you also add the `.orderBy("lastChat")` from the first part of my answer? If so, and you still get the problem, edit your question to show your updated code, the index definition, and the error message+stack trace.

Comment: this already works, before i made the wrong index, thanks

Comment: im sorry i forgot to accepted your answer, thanks